# Can a union of two entity types has its own unique key

Tags: entity-relationship

Can a union of two entity types has its own unique key.
I have a union (called payment) between loan and personnel funds. Loan can be from different banks under different loan schemes having a unique load ID. I want to model personnel funds as a weak entity with no key (cant think of a key for it). 
Payment should have a unique key called Payment ID and participates in a relation called 'buys' with a total participation constraint.

How can I model it. I have tried modelling it but I am not sure if its correct.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6TtC.png)

Comment: you may have base table which will hold unique id for all three. and beside this table may hold common data of three tables.

however without understanding your main intention. it is very hard to come up with decision

Comment: I need to model an EER for a car dealership. Short description of requirements goes as follows: A buyer can buy a car. Buyer can pay via a loan or personnel funds. Car dealership provides a couple of loan options based on customer credit history. I have a n ary relationship called "buy" between buyer, car, payment (where payment is a union of loan and personnel funds).

Comment: I still couldnt get why you need unique ID for all three. I believe that you have design concerns. You EE R diagram also is not comprehensive. making union of these tables like putting apples and bananas into the same basket.  in your payment table u can have payment_type and according to the payment type you can refer to loan table or personnel funds or even both.